# USB 3.0 noise blocking GPS signals

Tags: usb, noise, emc, gps, emi-filtering

We have designed a compact system that has:

1. Custom processing unit with USB phy and a USB 3.0 HUB (usb5744) with custom plastic USB connector.
2. USB 2.0 wifi module(external peripheral connected with wires)
3. USB 3.0 Camera (external peripheral connected with wires)
4. UART-based GPS module "L89H"(external peripheral connected with wires)

My issue is when the system runs with all peripherals, GPS is not able to get signals and not showing coordinates. After further debugging, we found that when the USB camera works with 3.0 connectivity this issue happens. The GPS module works fine when we use USB 2.0 cable for the camera, but due to bandwidth issues, we have to go with USB 3.0 camera connectivity only.

Is there anything I can do to make GPS work with USB 3.0?

Comment: Shield the GNSS antenna from the camera. The satellite signals are tiny so any interference has a significant effect.